# Read Binary File Bytes without Space

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I am reading a Binary File Bytes and converting them in to Hex.

```
Dim TempStr As String = String.Join(" ", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(flname).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")).ToArray())
```

Above code is working find But it is showing me Hex data with spaces between Bytes. Like:

> 00 50 45 00 00 4C 01 04 00 89 86 E3 51

What should I need to change on above code to get Hex values without space. I want to get these HEX values as:

> 00504500004C0104008986E351

Comment: Experiment with the first argument to your `String.Join` call.

Comment: You are **asking** it to add a space between each; perhaps try not doing that; `string.Join("", ...` maybe? or even just `string.Concat(...)` ?

Comment: Owh That's great thanks. I need many things to learn.. It worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between the `" "` after `String.Join(`

Like this:

```
Dim TempStr As String = String.Join("", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(flname).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")).ToArray())
```